Convert PyArrow table to pandas, but transform string to `string[pyarrow]` in pandas directly
Say I have
import pyarrow as pa

tbl = pa.table({'a': ['foo', 'bar']})

If I do tbl.to_pandas(), then the dtypes of the result are object:
In [14]: tbl.to_pandas().dtypes
Out[14]:
a    object
dtype: object

How can I convert tbl to pandas, such that column 'a' ends up being of type string[pyarrow]? I'd like this to happen during conversion, so tbl.to_pandas().convert_dtypes or anything like that which converts after the to_pandas call I can't accept

Found it:
tbl.to_pandas(types_mapper=lambda x: {pa.string(): pd.StringDtype(storage='pyarrow')}.get(x, None))


You can pass {pa.string(): pd.StringDtype(storage='pyarrow')}.get (no lambda).
